# Footnote after equation

Tags: equations, footnotes

Imagine I have an equation `$$ x=1+3$$ \footnote{Hello World!}`

How can I put the number of the footnote right beside the equation? I've tried doing just

`$x=1+3$ \footnote{Hello World!}`, but then the equation wouldn't be indented.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Edit since comment section erases spaces)

I get something like

```
      [indented equation]
```

(footnote_number)

And I would like to get

```
           [Indented equation](footnote_number)
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Using a footnote within the equation would be confusing at it would resemble a superscript/exponent. How do you want the output to look?

Comment: I get something like 
          [indented equation]
(footnote_number)

And I would like to get 

               [Indented equation](footnote_number)

Comment: Just put the `\footnote` inside the `\[...\]` (not `$$...$$`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you really need to have a numbered footnote you could use a symbol such as a dagger (symbol 2). Which would avoid confusion with a subscript or superscript

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\indent$ x=1+3$\footnote[2]{Hello World!}
```

This gives:

[image]

With a footnote of:

[image]